# Como controlar o contraste dos vídeos usando Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, chromium

No lado esquerdo está minha aplicação do Electron com um vídeo do youtube. No lado direito está a minha aplicação criada com pygtk2 e webkit. O contraste é melhor com o webkit. Com o Electron, o quadro negro ao redor do vídeo diverge. Como posso solucionar?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o Electron utiliza webm no chromium. A aplicação em webkit em python utiliza mp4. Por se tratar de um formato proprietário, mp4 não está disponível no Electron. A solução que encontrei para controlar essa diferença no contraste foi no uso de filtros css no elemento em questão.

```
-webkit-filter: contrast(120%);
```

Artigo abordando [filtros css](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/)